# Python vitual environment (venv): Share libraries in usage and dev/test venvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am new in python venv, so sorry for possible stupid question.

I am developing a small library. I've created dev virtual environment with all packages which is necessary for the library usage and freeze all versions of requirements to requirements.txt.

I also would like to create requirements_test.txt with all packages needed for development and tests. So the user will install requirements from requirements.txt while the developer from requirements_test.txt with all nessesary libs (e.g. pytest, asv, sphinx).

Now I've created dev venv and now I want to create test venv, of course I don't want to install the same libs twice. Is it possible to share some libs from one venv to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to share some libs from one venv to another?

No. The same library (or application) will be installed once per virtual environment, the installations can not be shared between environments. And it is perfectly fine like this. That is the whole point of virtual environments, that two installations from the same library are isolated from each other, in particular for the case where two different versions of the same library are required for two different projects.

To be completely fair, there are ways to share one installation of the same library between two virtual environments and reasons to do so. One famous example I know of currently is in the newer releases of [*virtualenv*](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) (versions 20+). In short: this tool creates virtual environments and (under specific conditions) is able to reuse (share) the installations of *pip*, *setuptools*, and *wheel* in multiple environments, see the [`app-data` seeder for *virtualenv*](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#seeders).

Some more discussions on the topic:

- https://discuss.python.org/t/proposal-sharing-distrbution-installations-in-general/2524
- https://discuss.python.org/t/optimizing-installs-of-many-virtualenvs-by-symlinking-packages/2983
- https://github.com/pypa/packaging-problems/issues/328

Answer (score 0):

You can use `virtualenv --system-site-packages` to symlink from the base system for sharing between dev and user. Then add the dev specific testing packages.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is recommended and advised to have multiple venvs, and multiple environments, be it on the same machine. so just have another venv. Its okay to have same library being present in both venvs.

Comment: This quickly adds up if the venvs only require one or two different libraries, though. When you have 5-6 different venvs each holding their own version of tf or torch... but I guess that's more of an engineering/standardisation problem

Answer (score -1):

Even with virtual environments, there are many libraries that come preinstalled with python and are not necessary in the package that you are developing, when I run `pip freeze` in a brand new virtual environment it dumps 30 packages, and surely they are not needed for my project.

I recommend you to do the dependency maintenance manually (at least the production ones), this way you won't include useless libraries and you will keep your dependency file clean.

Comment: I'm curious: "in a brand new virtual environment it dumps 30 packages", how is that possible?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer.

In my new usage venv there wasn't any package. And by freezing packages you protect yourself from the missing requarements.

Later you can delete some lines, for example, if lib you use have own requarements.