# How to use a single virtual environment with centralized common packages and install specific ones for each project/directory

Tags: python, directory, package, virtualenv

I would like to set up, if possible, one virtual environment and inside of it, common packages that will be used by all my projects. After that, I would like to install specific packages that will be reacheable only for the project right project, under a directory.

I see this structure like a tree with a root directory called **my_projects** where the virtual env will be active with the installed common packages for all the projects, and each subdirectory will be one project where the specific packages/version for that project will be used, and visible only in the required subdirectory, as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9APh.png)

I've browsed but could not found this specific configuration.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help you do what you seek? [Is it possible to create nested virtual environments for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019081/is-it-possible-to-create-nested-virtual-environments-for-python)

Comment: This might be...I will take a look...thanks